# UIImagePickerController movie storing in temp directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

The `UIImagePickerController` stores movies (if you recorded one) on disk in the temp directory before calling the `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` on the delegate.
But when are these stored movies removed from temp? Do I have to delete them manually or are they deleted automatically somehow.

I ask because I have a view, where the user can choose to record a movie and then this movie can be previewed in a `MPMoviePlayerView`. He can re-record the movie if he dislikes the current one. Do I have to delete these movies I don't use?

And what is the best practice for the movie the user chooses. This movie will be uploaded to a server. Should I copy/cut it to another directory (ex. documents) and delete it, when the upload is finished?

Tests with large movies revealed that my app-folders grow to inacceptable sizes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've run into this problem, I can't figure out why UIImagePickerController saves the movie in the tmp folder to begin with and not sure why it never gets released/erased. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: same problem - for love of god someone answer!

Comment: @SamBudda Did anyone figure this out? I can see that after you pick a movie you can do this         if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (mediaPath))
        {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (mediaPath, nil, nil, nil);
        }      But I can not figure out how to find the moviePath after it has been stored!

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't dig into it deeper as I no longer work at the project. As a workaround I manually deleted the movie after uploading it but that lead to unused random named directories.
But I'm still wondering why no one has a real solution for it.

Comment: If you choose more than one time same video than it stores every time new video in tmp directory I also facing the same prob but can't find any solution we have to remove manually? This will be increase more process. what to do?

Comment: Late to this thread, but it appears that this is as-designed functionality. iOS will eventually clean up the tmp files when it feels the need, but you should plan on deleting the temporary file when you are done with it.